# Set a default global pycharm project

Tags: python, pycharm

Before updating my pycharm, all my scripts used to open directly in a global default project where I can start editing and testing my code.

Now for some reason my script opens in some sort of basic editor in pycharm missing almost all the functionality. It looks like this.

[image]

I have to manually open my pycharm and drag my script into the pycharm window to open it like this way
[image]

I know this is a very trivial thing but I need help with the settings on how can I just open any script on my pc in the pycharm simply by double clicking without having to make individual project for each and everyone

Comment: usually when you right click on file in Windows/Linux file manager (not in PyCharm) you should see menu with `"open with ..."` and you can assign default program for this type of file (ie. `.py` files)

Comment: I use "Edit with pycharm community edition" but it opens as shown in the first image above

Comment: A project is usually a specific directory. So unless your script are in one place, I don't see how that is possible

Comment: Before the update I used to just double click on my script and start coding. I never made a project. I don't know if there is a setting I changed or something I don't remember but after updating pycharm, It doesn't work as usual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you started PyCharm in the light edit mode, check this blog post https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/04/lightedit-mode/